# Not showing any commit when it is already reverted?

Tags: git, github

I have merged a PR on `develop` branch but there was an issue on staging so I have reverted with the following command:

`git revert -m1 <commit>`
and then `git push` on `develop` branch

When I create a PR on Github to merge a feature branch to `develop`, it is not showing any commits/code on PR even though I have reverted the merge commit on develop branch.

What the issue and how to resolve this?

Comment: What relationship does the feature branch have with the merge and the revert commit? I ask because it isn't altogether clear why you expected the PR to contain any changes. You said you reverted the merge and then pushed that to develop, what did you do on the feature branch, can you outline what happened there that made you expect the PR to show changes?

Comment: I did not do any changes on a feature branch after revert merge commit on develop branch. Now I want to put it back to develop, but I was expecting to see the commit on the PR? It is showing blank code on PR.

Comment: If your feature branch has no commits, then there is nothing to merge. If you want to get the changes from the merge back into develop, the easiest is probably to revert the revert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two concepts need to be understood here.

1. While merging, git compares the commit hashes in the history of both the branches, to determine what commits to be merged.
2. `git revert` reverses the previous commit by creating a new commit. Refer [Git Revert  Doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert/2.22.0#_description). The previous commit will not be removed from the history.

Below is the current state of your develop branch.

```
c1 -- c2 -- merge commit -- revert commit
  \         / 
    c3 -- c4 

c3, c4 - commits that contain the feature branch changes
```

If you try to merge the feature branch now, since c4 commit is already in develop history, git will not take any action.

This can be resolved in following ways. There is a detailed discussion regarding this scenario in this [link](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a5fa49ff0a8f3252c6bff49f92b85e7683868f8a/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt#L139).

#### Create a patch and reapply the changes

1. In your feature branch, run `git log` to determine since which commit the changes needs to be merged to develop branch. (In our example, it was c3).
2. Create a patch. Run,
   `git format-patch <commit> <folder where patch file will be saved>`
3. Now merge the develop branch to your feature branch. `git merge origin/develop`. This will revert your changes in the feature branch as well.
4. Reapply the patches, `git apply --index <patch file>`.
5. Remember to make additional changes that were initially incorrect. Commit and push.

#### Revert the revert commit

As @Lasse mentioned, you can revert the revert commit. It is better to make these changes in feature branch and then raise a PR to develop branch.

1. Merge develop to feature branch
2. `git revert <revert commit>`
3. Make necessary corrections, commit and push the changes.

#### Rebase your feature branch

This is the least preferrable option, since it rewrites feature branch history. You can run `git rebase -i <since commit>` and just change the message of the first commit you want to merge. This will create new current and successive commit hashes and will allow you to merge it to develop. But there are 2 concerns.

1. There will be merge conflicts on your PR for all your changes. It is better you merge the develop to feature branch locally, solve the conflicts and push.
2. You need to force push, since you will be rewriting the history of remote feature branch